# "Improve this Document" link not appearing for vso (dev.azure.com) repository

Tags: c#, docfx

"Improve this Document" link not appearing for vso repository from deployed code.
"Improve this Document" link appear when debug from local code.
Already set following setting in docfx file but doesn't work in deployed code

```
 "_disableContribution": false,
 "_gitContribute": {
    "branch": "master",
    "repo": "https://dev.azure.com/testingorg/testingproject/_git/test"
  },
  "_gitUrlPattern": "vso"
```

How can I check reason of not generating the "Improve this Document" link?
if {{#docurl}} not generated then link doesn't appear, but working fine from local with same template, How to check the log  of not generating "Improve this Document" link?